# What can continuously block a scan area?

Tags: battlefield-4

In Battlefield 4 in commander mode I recently had a game where a large area was blocked from scanning for virtually the whole map (it started about mid game of a 3000 ticket game and then didn't end and didn't move an inch, or even a pixel for over 10 mins)

It was a very long match and the enemy commander used EMP UAV's in other places, so it wasn't that.

Was it a bug? A deployable? How can I counter this?

Comment: Note: During this period I also proxy attacked the enemy commander several times, the scan block remained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of forum trawling later; looks like this is a known bug if a commander logs off when a EMP UAV is up.

http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/en/forum/threadview/2955065217480972721/

Comment: Can confirm from own experience, that this is a bug. At least, there is no other reasonable explanation for that.